# DropDownListFor value cannot be null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC.  I am using a DropDownListFor to populate a number of Customer fields when a Company is selected.  I am using the following code for the DropDownListFor:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Customers, "CustomerId", "Company"), "---Select one---", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "company" } });
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Company)
```

This code retrieves the Customer data:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetCustomer(int custId)
{
    var data = db.Customers.Find(custId);
    return Json(data);
}
```

The relevant fields in the ViewModel (from the Customer table) are:

```
public int CustomerId { get; set; }
public string Company { get; set; }
```

The code in the Create method that creates the ViewBag:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    QuoteViewModel qvm = new QuoteViewModel();
    qvm.QuoteDetail = new List<QuoteDetail>(); 
    var customers = db.Customers.ToList();
    ViewBag.Customers = customers;
    return View(qvm);
}
```

And here is the code for the POST:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(QuoteViewModel qvm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Quote quote1 = new Quote();
        quote1.CustomerId = qvm.CustomerId;
        ...
        db.Quotes.Add(quote1);
        customer.CustomerId = qvm.CustomerId;
        ...
        db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
        bool saveFailed;
        do
        {
            saveFailed = false;
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                saveFailed = true;
                var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
                // Get failed entry
                var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
                // Now call refresh on ObjectContext
                objContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, entry.Entity);
            }
        } while (saveFailed);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(qvm);
}
```

The population of the fields works fine, but when I attempt to Create the view model I get an error "Value cannot be null" on the DropDownListFor.  I have researched others having this issue but cannot find an answer that applies to this case.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this happening when you submit (you need to show your POST method for `Create()`

Comment: Added above.  Thanks Stephen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because in the POST method you return the view (`ModelState` is invalid), but have not set the value of `ViewBag.Customers` as you did in the GET method, so it `null` and you cannot create a `SelectList` from a `null` collection.

Your need assign `ViewBag.Customers` as you did in the GET method before your `return View(qvm);` statement.

As a side note, since you using a view model, that view model should contain a property (say) `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CustomerList { get; set; }` and you set that in the controller methods, and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId, Model.CustomerList, "---Select one---", new { @class = "company" });
```

Comment: I added the ViewBag.Customers to the POST.  Now I am getting a validation error "Company name is required" even though the Company name has been selected in the DropDownListFor.

Comment: That is a completely separate issue and you have not shown the relevant code relating to that (see also my comment in the chat room - it makes no sense that you have a property `string Company`)

Answer (score 1):

Are you making a full page POST request when a Company is selected?
If you are, you need to fill **ViewBag.Customers** because of ViewBag's lifetime.

http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/viewdata-vs-viewbag-vs-tempdata-vs-session